# Solspace importer still updtates data with do nothing selected

Tags: solspace-importer

**EDIT**

**Nicolas from Solspace's Support came back to me with an answer :**

> I could reproduce the issue and reported this as a bug to our developers.

**Still, a patch would be welcome.**

---

We're using Solspace Importer 2.2.5 with ExpressionEngine 2.10

Importer is used to cron import members data from a csv.
Everything is running smoothly, except one thing :

Importer is updating existing member accounts while the drop down list in the import settings is set to *do nothing*.

We're filtering members upon username, we use a unique customer key number ( string like 12AB34 ) as username.

I opened a support ticked at solspace but got no answer till then.
Any advice would help, the site is e-commerce, and we're live.